# Importing Images from Another Folder

Tags: python, pygame

I am using this bit of code to import each of my images that I wish to use:

```
def load_all_graphics():
    image_dict = {}
    for filename in os.listdir("."):
        name,ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
        if ext.lower() in [".png",".jpg",".bmp"]:
            image = pg.image.load(filename).convert_alpha()
            image.set_colorkey(pg.Color("black"))
            image_dict[name] = image
    return image_dict

IMAGES = load_all_graphics()
```

It's working for the application I have, however the next thing I want to do is place the images in a seperate folder, I understand I need to change the "listdir", I have tried changing it to the folder containing my images - (Resources) however it becomes unable to open the image.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `filename` is only the filename relative to the directory you look up files. If you do not give the full path to the file, the script will try to open the file relative to the current directory, while the file is in another directory.

Solution: use `os.path.join` to create a full path to the file, like:

```
def load_all_graphics(dirname):
  image_dict = {}
  for filename in os.listdir(dirname):
    name,ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    if ext.lower() in [".png",".jpg",".bmp"]:
      pathname = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
      image = pg.image.load(pathname).convert_alpha()
      image.set_colorkey(pg.Color("black"))
        image_dict[name] = image
  return image_dict

IMAGES = load_all_graphics("/path/to/resources") 
print len(IMAGES)
```

Comment: I used "("C:\\Users\\James\\Desktop\\Nova\\Resources\\")" for the full dirname but it still fails to open the image.

Comment: @NezamiZeo: Is this still the same error? (btw I made a typo in my answer: of course on need to pass in the `pathname` to  `pg.image.load` after constructing it, not the `filename` :-/ fixed now)